# Span tag redirect page

Tags: html

I am trying to redirect my page once a image or a span tag is clicked.

This is my html code:

```
<a href="" class="dashboard-module">
                <img src="img/admin/Crystal_Clear_settings.gif" tppabs="http://www.xooom.pl/work/magicadmin/images/Crystal_Clear_settings.gif" width="64" height="64" alt="edit" />
                <span>Settings</span>
            </a>
```

Comment: it is simple.... use <a href="http://yournewlocation" ... >

Comment: You have not added any link in href.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="dashboard-module">
            <img src="img/admin/Crystal_Clear_settings.gif" tppabs="http://www.xooom.pl/work/magicadmin/images/Crystal_Clear_settings.gif" width="64" height="64" alt="edit" />
            <span>Settings</span>
        </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Span tags can't be used as links (unless you want to use javascript, which is a bad idea)
Looking at your snippet I'm guessing that you need the `<img>` and `span` wrapped within the `.dashboard-module` class.

here's how I would do it:

```
<div class="dashboard-module">
    <img src="img/admin/Crystal_Clear_settings.gif" tppabs="http://www.xooom.pl/work/magicadmin/images/Crystal_Clear_settings.gif" width="64" height="64" alt="edit" />
    <a href="#redirect-link"><span>Settings</span></a>
<div>
```

Comment: just reread your question, and you want both the img and the text as a link. I believe @Muhammad is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple, just put your link in anchor `href` tag.

```
<a href="www.example.com" class="dashboard-module">
  <img src="img/admin/Crystal_Clear_settings.gif" tppabs="http://www.xooom.pl/work/magicadmin/images/Crystal_Clear_settings.gif" width="64" height="64" alt="edit" />
  <span>Settings</span>
</a>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8CKZp/1/)